# Limit to only 1 selected checkbox

Tags: excel, ms-access, checkbox, excel-2010, vba

I have imported a table with check-boxes from Access to Excel. Is it possible to set the check-boxes where only one check-box can be selected from that imported table when using Excel?

Comment: Change the checkboxes to grouped radio buttons. By definition, ff you select one radio button from a group, all other radio buttons are unselected. If you coded the unselection of all other checkboxes when one is selected, all you are doing is duplicating the default behavior of grouped radio buttons.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments Jeeped made an excellent point that radio buttons already have the functionality that you are looking for. On the other hand -- if you prefer the aesthetics of checkboxes then you can certainly use them. I created a userform with two checkboxes in a frame (and no other controls in the frame) and also included a label for displaying the chosen option. The following code deselects all other checkboxes in the frame when one is selected. I used a non-local Boolean variable to circumvent the other checkbox's event handlers while they were being changed to avoid a sort of echo effect I ran into where the events were firing when I didn't want them to (perhaps there is a less kludgy way to do that). The code easily extends to any number of checkboxes in a grouping frame.

```
Dim selecting As Boolean 'module level variable

Private Sub SelectOne(i As Long)
    Dim c As Control
    selecting = True
    For Each c In Frame1.Controls
        If c.Name <> "CheckBox" & i Then c.Value = False
    Next c
    DoEvents
    Label1.Caption = i & " selected"
    selecting = False
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If Not selecting Then SelectOne 1
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    If Not selecting Then SelectOne 2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works best and its much easier - at least for a few boxes - for more you could write some formulas in excel and drag down then copy as values and copy paste text from excel into vba. Anyway, here it's how I did it:
I went and created code under each button - quite basic

```
Private Sub DateCheckBox1_Click()
If DateCheckBox1.Value = True Then
    DateCheckBox2.Value = False
    DateCheckBox3.Value = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub DateCheckBox2_Click()
If DateCheckBox2.Value = True Then
    DateCheckBox3.Value = False
    DateCheckBox1.Value = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub DateCheckBox3_Click()
If DateCheckBox3.Value = True Then
    DateCheckBox2.Value = False
    DateCheckBox1.Value = False
End If
End Sub
```